# homepage regexp matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regexp which allow me to filter out all the url addresses having this shape.

```
http://foo.com/
http://foo
http://foo.*
```

But not the following:

```
http://foo.com/subfoo
http://foo.com/subfoo/
http://foo.com/subfoo/subsubfoo..
```

In order to match the second url group i've written the following regexp:

```
http://.*/.
```

However my problem is search the regexp matching the first group. 
So i need a way to say:

```
if after http://.* or http.//.*/ there is nothing, matches the pattern.
```

I've read something on lookhaead. I don't know it this might be the right way. 
Any idea? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but this worked for me:

```
http://[^/]*[/]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^http:\/\/[^/?#]*\/./i
```

should match only http URLs with a path component other than `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget query strings like this: `http://foo.com/?search`

```
/^http:\/\/[^/?#]*\/[^?]/i
```

Comment: Good point.  You might want to include # in that last charset